# HackerRank says ~ no response on stdout ~ Swift

Tags: swift

I'm taking a course with a hands-on question on Swift programming, that redirect me to Hackerrank

Write a function named printMessage that takes two parameters - a string message and an integer count. The message should print and repeat the message as specified in the count parameter.

Message:"Hello , How are You"

For instance take Count as 8

This should print Message:"Hello , How are You" 8 times consecutively.

The problem is when I submit my code always said Wrong answer, then I tried with custom input, and it throws me no response on STDOUT.
Anyone knows what's wrong?

```
import Foundation 

func printMessage(message: String, count: Int) {

    for _ in 0..<count {
        print(message)

    }
}

let message: String = readLine()!
let count: Int = Int(readLine()!)!
printMessage(message: message, count: count)
```

Comment: Doesn't hackerrank automatically generate inputs and run the function? What happens if you delete last 3 lines and just edit inside function on hackerrank. Just leave the function.

Comment: @emrepun it throws the same, wrong answer, and if I use custom output no response on stdout

Comment: Is challenge link publicly available? I would like to take a look and investigate what might be the reason for error.

Comment: No, is not public that´s the problem, I'm currently working at TCS and is one quiz of a course from Frescoplay. I think the quiz is easy, but something is wrong with hackerrank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run into this before, the way I solved it was saving my code somewhere and resetting to the boilerplate code. So just reset to the boilerplate and copy your function back in. On many swift hackerrank problems they have something like the following:

```
func myFunc(param: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    /*
    * Write your code here.
    */
}

// The following is an example of your function being written to stdout

let fileName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["OUTPUT_PATH"]!
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: fileName, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: fileName)!

let result = myFunc(param: input)

fileHandle.write(result.map{ String($0) }.joined(separator: "\n").data(using: .utf8)!)
fileHandle.write("\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
```

The code after the function is what writes to stdout

Comment: you're right, but now it sends me Runtime Error ~message masked~

Comment: @RobertoGarcía that sounds like an issue with your code that you need to debug. If this answered your initial question could you please mark accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Hackerrank in some swift exercises fires that message whenever you have a buffer overflow, instead of warning you about it